# How to transpose rows into dynamic columns in Oracle 10

Tags: oracle, dynamic, transpose, dynamic-columns

I have a table called TEST_HIST that gets updated daily with a PASS/FAIL status for each test in a battery of 1800 tests. The table is in Oracle 10.

I need to produce the following report where each daily result set appears in a column

```
ID     05/07/13  05/08/13  05/09/13     
A0001  PASS      PASS      PASS     
G0002  FAIL      FAIL      FAIL   
X0003  FAIL      PASS      PASS
```

The Table TEST_HIST looks like this:

```
ID, Date, Test_Result  
'A0001','05/07/13','PASS'  
'G0002','05/07/13','FAIL'  
'X0003','05/07/13','FAIL'  

'A0001','05/08/13','PASS'  
'G0002','05/08/13','FAIL'  
'X0003','05/08/13','PASS'   

'A0001','05/09/13','PASS'  
'G0002','05/09/13','FAIL'  
'X0003','05/09/13','PASS'
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'd need to use dynamic SQL to generate a new query each time.  It would also require scanning the table once to get the set of date values and then the cost of actually running the query and pivoting the data.  What language would you be using to generate that dynamic SQL statement?  Are you using `DBMS_SQL`?  Would you be building the SQL statment in Java or C# or VB or some other language?

Comment: Is there to be a fixed(or max) number of days?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 and connecting to Oracle 10 to query this data, so it's going to be PLSQL I guess.    Also the test period is 2 months, so there will be approximately 40 test dates.